# Fvm requires permission on Windows

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-design, fvm

I am using Fvm v2.4.1 and using commands like:

- `fvm list`
- `fvm config`
- `fvm doctor`

It work fine, but when `fvm use <version> --verbose` is entered it displays:

```
[0.076s] Version: 3.0.3 - already installed.
[0.097s] FileSystemException: Cannot create link to target 'C:\Users\user\fvm\versions\3.0.3', path = 'I:\ASHISH\mela\.fvm\flutter_sdk' (OS Error: A required privilege is not held by
 the client.
, errno = 1314)
[0.098s] Usage Exception: Seems you don't have the required permissions on C:\Users\user\fvm On Windows FVM requires to run as an administrator or turn on developer mode: https://bit
.ly/3vxRr2M
```

I have searched but could not find the way out,
How can i add the permission on windows 10 , i m using android studio.

[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YogGp.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

The solution to the problem is in the hint:

```
Seems you don't have the required permissions on C:\Users\user\fvm On Windows FVM requires to run as an administrator or turn on developer mode:
```

All you have to do is run your `powershell`|`cmd` as administrator and try again. Also, running the ide as administrator may help.

Comment: Thank you.  We need to go to Windows setting and give required permission .that it,

Comment: can you explain this?